# Chef - add/change a line in a file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to Chef / Kitchen. I'd like to change a line in a file on the target VM, such like `/etc/sudoers` - change `Defaults ...`.

That means, I don't want to use `template` which would overwrite the file - I want to retain the other content of the file.

Ideally I would like some action like this:

```
file_changeLine '/path/to/file/' do
    prefix: "Defaults .*"
end
```

Is there something such? I haven't found in [docs](https://docs.chef.io/files.html). Maybe there are some additional repositories with community-made actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We really don't recommend this kind of management structure, but if you must, look at the `poise-file` and `line` cookbooks on Supermarket. They provide resource-based interfaces for delta updates. Just be aware that this will need a lot of care and feeding as it leads to generally brittle code.

Comment: I understand that that way I take the burden of maintainance on myself, but what other option do I have? Most linux configs are line-based, proprietary syntax. If it was XML or such, or had an API, it would be easier.

Comment: There are a few options. The simplest is control the whole file with one template resource, but that can be hard. For sudoers in particular, and many other tools, you can use the `include foo.d/*.conf` style and then use a template for just the little bit you need. Most standard `sudoers` files come with the by default these days.

Comment: Ok but that moves the problem to "how to add an `include` line to `/etc/sudoers`... And we are where we were. I need to retain the distro's defaults.

Comment: “Need” is relative, copy the current distro file into a template and add what you want, and then own the whole file from that point forward.

Comment: If there is a file with 200 lines which often changes, and I only need to change one, "owning" the file doesn't seem too practical. Changing one line in a recipe sounds more suitable for that case. Thanks, I will try `line`.